# Py2app app unable to find poppler in path

Tags: python, py2app, poppler

So I created a simple TKinter app that converts pdfs to jpgs using pdf2image, and the script works completely as expected. I decided to try to deploy this as a Mac application, and I get "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?". Poppler is required by pdf2image, and I have it installed in my path, but obviously thats not carrying over to the py2app resources. So I'm not sure what I should change to have this work in my app.

Heres the setup.py:

````
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['pdf2jpg.py']
OPTIONS = {'includes': ["pdf2image", "os", "Pillow", "tkinter", "stitching", "poppler"],
           'packages': ["pdf2image"]}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    # Path to poppler (I think)
    resources=["/opt/homebrew/bin"]
)```
````